# Statistical distribution plot with shaded rejection areas

Tags: r, plot, distribution

I found this R code online:

```
stdDev <- 0.75;
x <- seq(-5,5,by=0.01)
y <- dnorm(x,sd=stdDev)
right <- qnorm(0.95,sd=stdDev)
plot(x,y,type="l",xaxt="n",ylab="p",
     xlab=expression(paste('Assumed Distribution of ',bar(x))),
     axes=FALSE,ylim=c(0,max(y)*1.05),xlim=c(min(x),max(x)),
     frame.plot=FALSE)
axis(1,at=c(-5,right,0,5),
     pos = c(0,0),
     labels=c(expression(' '),expression(bar(x)[cr]),expression(mu[0]),expression('')))
axis(2)
xReject <- seq(right,5,by=0.01)
yReject <- dnorm(xReject,sd=stdDev)
polygon(c(xReject,xReject[length(xReject)],xReject[1]),
        c(yReject,0, 0), col='red')
```

It is doing what I need, which is plotting the normal distribution, and shading a right rejection area according to some number (0.95). What I want to ask is:

1. How can I change this code to shade a two sided rejection area?
2. How do I change it for a left side one sided area?
3. And assume that I want a chi square or F distribution instead, is it enough to just change the dnorm & qnorm commands accordingly?
4. Another question: In this plot, the plot itself is higher than the y-axis. How do I fix it that the axis matches the height of the plot?

Thank you!

Comment: I noted that you never have "accepted" (ticked checkmark) any answer in you SO career, even if you got good responses in most cases. Please try to follow the rules.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can start with a polygon covering the whole area under the curve and removing the part that is not rejected:

   ```
   ## Calculate the 5th percentile
   left <- qnorm(0.05,sd=stdDev)

   ## x and y for the whole area
   xReject <- c(seq(-5,5,by=0.01))
   yReject <- dnorm(xReject,sd=stdDev)

   ## set y = 0 for the area that is not rejected  
   yReject[xReject > left & xReject < right] <- 0

   ## Plot the red areas
   polygon(c(xReject,xReject[length(xReject)],xReject[1]),
           c(yReject,0, 0), col='red')
   ```
2. As before but set to zero the not rejected areas

   ```
   yReject[xReject > left] <- 0
   ```
3. Almost. For example for the chi squared distribution you have to give the df (degrees of freedom and not sd). And also the `xlim` has to be changed. But apart from that the code would be the same.
4. The line `axis(2)` draws the y-axis. You can give some extra arguments to have it the way you want. You can try for example:

   ```
   s <- seq(0,0.55,0.05)
   axis(2, at = s, labels = s)
   ```

Hope it helps,

alex

Answer (score 1):

Take the `polygon` calls which shade the right-side rejection area and repeat those lines, substituting the coordinates of the left-side area.

i think this will do it

```
left <- qnorm(0.05,sd=stdDev)
xLeject <- seq(left,-5,by=-0.01)
yLeject <- dnorm(xLeject,sd=stdDev)
polygon(c(xLeject,xLeject[length(xLeject)],xLeject[1]),
        c(yLeject,0, 0), col='red')
```

As to graph extent, see `plot(..., ylim=(lower,upper))`

Comment: it isn't working, I did it, but it colored the entire area from 0.05 to infinity with red. I wanted 0.05 to -infinity and 0.95 to infinity

Comment: @user3275222 then fiddle with the arguments to `left - qnorm(...,lower.tail=TRUE)` . Check the help page for `qnorm`

Comment: @user3275222 James Trimble's edits appear to do the job.  I dunno if these edits have been published, so check for `left <- qnorm(0.05,sd=stdDev)`